# Php : How to add odd/even loop to my unordered list

Tags: php, css, xhtml

Here an example my wordpress post. I want to add some class to **the last** of `<li>`

something like **`<li class='lastli'>`**

```
<ul class="tabs">
 <?php
  global $post;
  $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3');
  foreach($myposts as $post) :
  setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
 <li><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>         
</ul>
```

The results I wanted to be like :

```
<ul>
 <li>Title 1</li>
 <li>Title 1</li>
 <li class='lastli'>Title 1</li>
<ul>
```

Any last of unordered lists will be `<li class='lastli'>`. Let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a for loop

```
<ul class="tabs">
 <?php
  global $post;
  $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3');
  $nposts = count($myposts);
  for($i=0;$i<$nposts;$i++):
    $post = $myposts[$i];
    setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
 <li<?php if ($i==$nposts-1):?> class='lastli'<?php endif;?>><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
 <?php endfor; ?>         
</ul>
```

*Note: counting your array size before the loop is good practice, otherwise php will evaluate it at every round of the loop*

Comment: Thanks Ben 10! real super fix. `:?> class` need to have a white space.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="tabs">
 <?php
  global $post;
  $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3');
  $nposts = count($myposts);
  $odd_even_class = array('odd_class', 'even_class');

  for($i=0;$i<$nposts-1;$i++):
    $post = $myposts[$i];
    setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
 <li <?php echo $odd_even_class[($i+1)%2];?>><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
 <?php 
endfor; 
 $post = $myposts[$i];
 setup_postdata($post);

 <li class='lastli'><a href="#"><?php the_title();?></a></li>         
</ul>
```

**You need no Conditional statement :)**

Comment: I'm not sure if an array look up is faster than a conditional test :) Also, you probably don't need $curr_class, you could just use $i%2 as the index.. and the array should probably be array('even_class', 'odd_class')

Comment: I have made the odd/even class selection technique. I have said - "You need no Conditional statement :)", because of your last row selection condition, at least I have avoided that one easily :). Not about odd/even.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="tabs">
 <?php
  global $post;
  $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3');
  $i = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($myposts); $i++) {
  $post = $myposts[$i];
  setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
 <li <?= ($i==count($myposts)-1)?"class='lastli'":"" ?>><a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>         
</ul>
```